# How can we prove that a continuous function with $f(x) = f(x+1000)$ is constant?

Tags: functions

The original problem :

> if $f(x) = f(x+1000)$ for any x
>
> and $\int_0^3f(x) = 30 $
>
> What is $\int_3^5f(x+2016)$

I only know that if $f(x) = 10$ it will fulfill all of the conditions, but I don't know how to prove it.
Thank you.

Comment: It is not the only solution

Comment: Just find a function f:[0,1000) such that the second condition holds and copy it on all of the interval

Comment: Your edited body does not agree with your title anymore.

Comment: I think you have copied the original problem wrong.  The one here cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

A periodic function with period 1000 or any other number need not be constant. Im the context of your problem, consider $f, g$ on [0, 1000) given by $f(x) = 10$ and $g(x) = 20x/3$ and let $\hat f, \hat g$ be their periodic continuations on $\mathbb R$ respectively (if you don’t know what periodic continuation is, it is what you think it is). Clearly, both functions satisfy the given conditions. However, $$\int_{2019}^{2021} \hat f = \int_{19}^{21} f = 20 \neq 800/3 = \int_{19}^{21} g = \int_{2019}^{2021} \hat g.$$ Therefore, the answer is not unique. Perhaps you are asked to find all possible values of the integral or there is a condition missing? Nonetheless, the problem is rather strange. In this form, you could rather easily prove that any real number is possible for the integral to attain.